# Java; casting base class to derived class

Tags: java, casting, class

Why can't I cast a base class instance to a derived class?

For example, if I have a class B which extends a class C, why can't I do this?

```
B b=(B)(new C());
```

or this?

```
C c=new C();
B b=(B)c;
```

---

Alright let me be more specific as to what I'm trying to do. Here's what I have:

```
public class Base(){
    protected BaseNode n;
    public void foo(BaseNode x){
        n.foo(x);
    }
}


public class BaseNode(){
    public void foo(BaseNode x){...}
}
```

Now I want to create a new set of classes which extend Base and Basenode, like this:

```
public class Derived extends Base(){
    public void bar(DerivedNode x){
        n.bar(x);//problem is here - n doesn't have bar
    }
}

public class DerivedNode extends BaseNode(){
    public void bar(BaseNode){
        ...
    }
}
```

So essentially I want to add new functionality to Base and BaseNode by extending them both, and adding a function to both of them. Furthermore, Base and BaseNode should be able to be used on their own.

I'd really like to do this without generics if possible.

---

Alright so I ended up figuring it out, partly thanks to Maruice Perry's answer.

In my constructor for `Base`, `n` is instantiated as a `BaseNode`. All I had to do was re-instantiate `n` as a `DerivedNode` in my derived class in the constructor, and it works perfectly.

Comment: First off, you need to make BaseNode n; protected so that Derived can see it.

Comment: I mean is there not any way of doing this without generics? Like I said I want the base classes to be useable as-is - adding generics would make them more cumbersome to use, and removes the encapsulation of the BaseNode class which is supposed to be encapsulated by Base.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the ***instanceof*** keyword to check the type of object referenced by ***n*** and typecast the object and call the ***bar()*** method. Checkout ***Derived.bar()*** method bellow

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        DerivedNode dn = new DerivedNode();
        Derived d = new Derived(dn);
        d.bar( dn );
    }
}

class Base{
    protected BaseNode n;
    public Base(BaseNode _n){
        this.n = _n;
    }

    public void foo(BaseNode x){
        n.foo(x);
    }
}


class BaseNode{
    public void foo(BaseNode x){
        System.out.println( "BaseNode foo" );
    }
}

class Derived extends Base{
    public Derived(BaseNode n){
        super(n);
    }

    public void bar(DerivedNode x){
        if( n instanceof DerivedNode ){
            // Type cast to DerivedNode to access bar
            ((DerivedNode)n).bar(x);
        }
        else {
            // Throw exception or what ever
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Object Type");
        }
    }
}

class DerivedNode extends BaseNode{
    public void bar(BaseNode b){
        System.out.println( "DerivedNode bar" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

because if B extends C, it means B is a C and not C is a B.

rethink what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've edited my post and have added what it is I'm actually trying to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 20):

The existing answers are fine in terms of an abstract argument, but I'd like to make a more concrete one. Suppose you *could* do that. Then this code would have to compile and run:

```
// Hypothetical code
Object object = new Object();
InputStream stream = (InputStream) object; // No exception allowed?
int firstByte = stream.read();
```

Where exactly would the implementation of the `read` method come from? It's abstract in `InputStream`. Where would it get the data from? It simply *isn't appropriate* to treat a bare `java.lang.Object` as an `InputStream`. It's much better for the cast to throw an exception.

In my experience it's tricky to get "parallel class hierarchies" like the one you're describing to work. You *may* find that generics help, but it can get hairy very quickly.

Comment: Thanks Jon. After some additional thinking this totally makes sense. Another explanation could be this: We can already cast a derived class to a base class - which means we can cast anything to an Object. However, if we could cast a base class to a derived class, we could effectively cast an Object as anything. If we could do both of those things, any class could be casted to any other class - which clearly does not make sense.

Thanks for the help, and the validation in that 'parallel class hiarchies' are a pain to get working :)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a constructor for B that takes C as a parameter.
See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895552/) for ideas to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Base classes shouldn't know anything about classes derived from them, otherwise the problems highlighted above will arise. Downcasting is a 'code smell', and downcasting in the base class to a derived class is particularly 'smelly'. Such designs can lead to difficult to resolve circular dependencies too.

If you want a base class to make use of derived class implementations use the Template method pattern i.e add a virtual or abstract method in your base class and override and implement it in the derived class. You can then safely call this from the base class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that because C does not necessarily implement the behaviours you created when you extended it in B.

So, say C has a method `foo()`. Then you know that you can call `foo()` on a B, as B extends C, so you can cast accordingly a treat a B as if it was a C with `(C)(new B())`.

However - if B has a method `bar()`, nothing in the subclass relationship says that you can call `bar()` on C too. Thus you cannot treat a C as if it were a B, and so you cannot cast.

Answer (score 2):

In your exemple, you can cast n into a DerivedNode if you are certain that n is an instance of DerivedNode, or you can use generics:

```
public class Base<N extends BaseNode> {
    protected N n;
    public void foo(BaseNode x){
        n.foo(x);
    }
}


public class BaseNode {
    public void foo(BaseNode x){...}
}

public class Derived extends Base<DerivedNode> {
    public void bar(DerivedNode x){
        n.bar(x); // no problem here - n DOES have bar
    }
}

public class DerivedNode extends BaseNode {
    public void bar(BaseNode){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! "In your exemple, you can cast n into a DerivedNode if you are certain that n is an instance of DerivedNode" was extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Because if `B extends C`, then B might have stuff that isn't in C (like instance variables you initialize in the constructor that are not in new C())