# ClassCastException class extends android.location.Location

Tags: android, location, classcastexception, extends

Here's another bug that I just can't figure out.

I've got this class `ExtendedLocation extends Location` that
throws `ClassCastException` when instantiated by 
`currentGpsLocation = new ExtendedLocation((ExtendedLocation) location);`

Looking at the stack trace tells me absolutely nothing about a
possible solution. Maybe someone smarter than me, can chime in.

I'm pretty new at this java/android stuff, so this might be a simple problem
to some, just not for me.

---

**The Exception**

```
: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.location.Location
:   at ru.alperez.gpsdub.GpsActivity$1.onLocationChanged(GpsActivity.java:485)
:   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:227)
:   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:160)
:   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:176)
:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
:   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

**ExtendedLocation.class**

```
package ru.alperez.model;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.location.Location;

public class ExtendedLocation extends Location{

    public ExtendedLocation(ExtendedLocation l) {
        super(l);
    }

    public ExtendedLocation(String provider) {
        super(provider);
    }

    public JSONObject toJSON() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject ret = new JSONObject();
        ret.put("accuracy", this.getAccuracy());
        ret.put("altitude", this.getAltitude());
        ret.put("bearing", this.getBearing());
        ret.put("lat", this.getLatitude());
        ret.put("lon", this.getLongitude());
        ret.put("provider", this.getProvider());
        ret.put("speed", this.getSpeed());
        ret.put("time", this.getTime());
        return ret;
    }

    public static ExtendedLocation fromJSON(JSONObject jLocation) {
        ExtendedLocation ret = null;
        try {
            ret = new ExtendedLocation(jLocation.optString("provider"));
            ret.setAccuracy((float) jLocation.optDouble("accuracy"));
            ret.setAltitude(jLocation.optDouble("altitude"));
            ret.setBearing((float) jLocation.optDouble("bearing"));
            ret.setLatitude(jLocation.optDouble("lat"));
            ret.setLongitude(jLocation.optDouble("lon"));
            ret.setSpeed((float) jLocation.optDouble("speed"));
            ret.setTime(jLocation.optLong("time"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ret = null;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

---

**The offending code**

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "LocationListener::onLocationChanged: "+location);
        try
        {
            currentGpsLocation = new ExtendedLocation((ExtendedLocation) location);
            Log.d(TAG, "LocationListener::onLocationChanged:currentGpsLocation "+currentGpsLocation);
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"ExtendedLocation failed.",e);
            return;
        }
        if (!USE_NMEA) {
            populateCurrentGpsData(currentGpsLocation, lastFixState, referenceGpsPoint);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm impressed. Question asked 8 min. ago. 19 views and 4 answers. Cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onLocationChanged` is called by `LocationManager`. The object is passed by that manager, it's not an object of your class. Instead of having a constructor like you have there:

```
public ExtendedLocation(ExtendedLocation l) {
    super(l);
}
```

try to replace it with:

```
public ExtendedLocation(Location l) {
    super(l);
}
```

and this line from `onLocationChanged`

```
  currentGpsLocation = new ExtendedLocation((ExtendedLocation) location);
```

becomes:

```
  currentGpsLocation = new ExtendedLocation(location);
```

Comment: Yes, that get rid of the exception. I would have voted +1, if I had the reputation points.

Comment: I've been looking for somewhere to set closed/accepted/solved status. No luck so far.

Comment: **Got it** I finally found the `help` link at the top ;^)

Comment: make sure you have as much accepted answers as possible as this is the "engine" that runs SO.

Answer (score 0):

Change parameter of the constructor of `ExtendedLocation` to `Location` and remove class casting from calling this:
`currentGpsLocation = new ExtendedLocation(location);`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast a `Location` to an `ExtendedLocation`:

```
currentGpsLocation = new ExtendedLocation((ExtendedLocation) location);
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^ here ^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is not allowed. An `ExtendedLocation` is a `Location`. This is not true for the other way around: A `Location` is not an `ExtendedLocation`. Thus, a `Location` can not be casted to an `ExtendedLocation`.

However, you don't need this. You have to change two spots:

Change the above line to

```
currentGpsLocation = new ExtendedLocation(location);
```

and change the constructor of the class `ExtendedLocation` to take a `Location` instead of an `ExtendedLocation`:

```
public ExtendedLocation(Location l) {
    super(l);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that get rid of the exception. I would have voted +1, if I had the reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

Your ExtendedLocation should take a Location class object as parameter in consutructor. You also can't cast location object to ExtendLocation.

Answer (score 0):

Base classes shouldn't know anything about classes derived from them, otherwise the problems highlighted above will arise. Downcasting is a 'code smell', and downcasting in the base class to a derived class is particularly 'smelly'. Such designs can lead to difficult to resolve circular dependencies too.

If you want a base class to make use of derived class implementations use the Template method pattern i.e add a virtual or abstract method in your base class and override and implement it in the derived class. You can then safely call this from the base class.

Follow the link below for methods to cast:

[Java; casting base class to derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572348/java-casting-base-class-to-derived-class)